# In binding a custom type must I also bind all other types that show up in the custom type's API?

Tags: pybind11

True or False

> To bind a custom type/class in C++ you must also bind any other types that show up in the custom type's API as well as any further types that show up in the constructors of those involved other types.

I'm looking to bind a bunch of custom data types in a project I just started on and am looking to scope out the degree of work involved.

It seems like for pybind to bind a specific type it needs to also know about any other types that show up either as method arguments and or return values from any of the type's methods. Additionally in order to construct those other types you must also bind any further types involved in those other types' constructors. Basically one has to recursively bind all the types in the dependency graph that intersect in the type to be bound's public API and all involved constructors. Is that accurate? Did I miss anything?

Comment: True, Python has to know how to interpret the values that it holds. So you have the bind return values (of the functions/methods you wrap), and for any practical relevance also the input arguments. You don't have do this all in the same library though. If the library from which you use a class has a Python API already you can just import it at (Python) runtime

Comment: At the same time, if your question would be more specific, with a minimal example, it could actually be answered, rather than commented

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll update with an example that tries to exhaustively tease out all the areas where binding can proliferate down that relevant slice of the dependency graph. So far I've identified 3 cases in my real world work, the constructor argument chains down to the first constructor that is void or fully with primitive types alone, also method return types, and finally input arguments to methods.